# FB.Event.subscribe object return

Tags: javascript, facebook

I would like to know what is the structure of the object the function FB.Event.subscribe return when i use the following code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
    alert("Thank you for leaving a comment! :)");
});
```

thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
alert (JSON.stringify(response));
```

to get the full response. That works for any object, actually.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use console.log(response) to have a look at the object, I find that an alert box is insufficient for large objects. (I use facebook with the firebug extension installed)